# on TypeScript, on a generic function declaration can we use ReturnType and Parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a generic wrapper function, and thought that this would work, but it is not:

```
function wrapFunctionWithLogging<T extends Function>(f: (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>): ReturnType<T>  {
      return function (...args: Parameters<T>) {
        console.log('before ');
        try {
          return f(...args);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          throw error;
        } finally {
          console.log('done');
        }
      };
    }
```

I got another version with two types like

```
wrapFunctionWithLogging<TArgs extends any[], TReturn>
```

and it is working fine, I am curious why this version would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(...args: any[]) => any` to describe any function instead. Your wrapper should take a function with this signature and return a function with the same signature, so they're actually both simply `T`. You also need to assert that the return type is `T` as well.

```
function wrapFunctionWithLogging<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(f: T): T {
    return function (...args: any[]) {
        console.log("before");
        try {
            return f(...args);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        } finally {
            console.log("done");
        }
    } as T;
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wj1EkW)

Comment: This works fine without lots of type decoration, I think the key is the final cast as T part. I really like the use of type assertion here.

Comment: got it working without type assertion:)

Answer (score 1):

building on the idea of extending from a function with arguments seems to work, without type assertion:)

```
function wrapFunctionWithLogging<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(f: T): (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> {
  return function (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> {
    console.log('before ');
    try {
      return f(...args);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    } finally {
      console.log('done');
    }
  };
}
```

[TS Fiddle here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgO4CcCGAHAYpWRCAdThgAsAZBAcxrghoB4AVZAUwA8Z2IATAM7IAFADpxmdDQEAuZJggBPANoBdAJTIAvAD55SncJByW6uWIlTZyAAqTMAW3Y90A1js27kAJWdh0ECyK2OzuyADewMjI6H4ByODQ8Egi4qKS0nJ2WE4ubiwecr4w-oHBoQURUdHIUEgCCAA27KKNtMIA5ABG7CAIscgd6gDc1dEw6IpVNTWxJfEgFulWI2PIAL61mDBQ5CLs6Oj9mpEz0XUQDc2iB0fowrfHo2fIFEeoHIf9zzWbIAyYRqNKanM4XK4tNo0Tp8JDsIY-aLrarrUbI8EwZB8MDYRpwKDbdjaESYGQQMAOHroTx6TDIABUyAATKMMWgsNgQnwACI4vEEnjEjA4fBJIikCjUOgMaHY3H4wmrcFNSHtYWc9g8vkKnjCACMAAZ1OpgEA)

Comment: Quite longer than using a type assertion, but whatever floats your boat, I guess.

Comment: I was frustrated that I could not get the Parameters<T> declaration working, just happy to get it working finally.